# QuickReport.ExportToFilter throws "stack overflow" error when used in TWebModule

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I have a web application using the TWebModule component.  It runs as a module on Apache.  The code below throws a "Stack Overflow" error on the ExportToFilter.  The same exact code works fine from a Winforms Application and even a service for that matter.  I have seen other discussions on this which indicate it has something to do with threading.

```
var
  mFileName: String;
  AExportFilter:;
begin
    mFileName := 'c:\temp\calendar.pdf';
    AExportFilter:=TQRPDFDocumentFilter.Create(mFileName);
    try

      WebSchdHistCalendarForm := TWebSchdHistCalendarForm.create(nil);
      WebSchdHistCalendarForm.quickrep1.ShowProgress := False;
      WebSchdHistCalendarForm.quickrep1.ExportToFilter(AExportFilter  );
    finally
     AExportFilter.Free;
     WebSchdHistCalendarForm.Free;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you get Stack overflow on infinite recursive method calls. This might not be the case here though.

Comment: It raises a non-Delphi exception (ntdll.rtlconvertuLongToLargeInteger) within the cvtInt function of QRPDFFilt.pas

Answer (score 0):

Only 11 years late, but this might be useful to someone else, as I've just encountered this problem with one of my applications running on some Windows 10 machines.

*(Actually in my case the Windows event log reported it as an access violation, but by running WinDbg on one of the problem machines I was able to see the initial cause was a stack overflow at the cvtInt() function.)*

The fix is to mark the Buf parameter as **const** in a couple of functions in QRPDFFilt.pas:

```
function cvtInt(Buf: array of byte; P: Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result:=(256*Buf[P])+(Buf[P+1]);
end;
```

should be:

```
function cvtInt(const Buf: array of byte; P: Integer) : Integer;
begin
  Result:=(256*Buf[P])+(Buf[P+1]);
end;
```

and likewise for cvtDWord():

```
function cvtDWord(const Buf: array of byte; P: Integer) : DWORD;
```

(Thanks to Marco Filho for this solution, found on [devmedia.com.br](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/tqrpdfdocumentfilter-trava-o-sistema-no-windows-10/590099))